# Twist of Curves (AEC example 2.4)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I have an elementary question about twists of curves. The reference I am using is Silverman's AEC. In the book, the Galois action on the twisted function field $\bar{K}(C)_\xi$ is defined as $\sigma \cdot f= f^\sigma \xi_\sigma $ where $\xi: G_{\bar{K}/k} \to Isom(E)$ a 1 cocycle. (by $f^\sigma$ I denote the original action and by $\sigma \cdot f$ the twisted one.)

He then proceeds to give an example of a quadratic twist, which is what I am trying to understand. In particular let $L=K(\sqrt d)$ a quadratic extension, $\chi:G_{\bar{K}/K}\to \{\pm 1\}$ by $\chi(\sigma)=\frac{(\sqrt{d})^\sigma}{\sqrt d}$ and $\xi_\sigma=[\chi(\sigma)]$ the 1-cocycle. Let $E/K$ an elliptic curve given by $y^2=f(x)$. We want to see how $G=G_{\bar{K}/K}$ acts on the twisted function field. Note that $[-1](x,y)=(x,-y)$

Here is where Silverman says that $x^\sigma=x$.  By that I suppose he means the twisted action, which I denote by $\sigma \cdot x$ (?). If that's the case then $\sigma \cdot x$ by definition should be $x^\sigma \xi_\sigma=x^\sigma$ which is where I am stuck as I get that $\sigma \cdot x= x^\sigma$ instead of $\sigma \cdot x = x$

Similarly I get that $\sigma \cdot y= \chi(\sigma)y^\sigma$ while he gets that $ \sigma \cdot y= \chi(\sigma)y$.

I know I am doing an elementary mistake here, but I would appreciate any hints on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Admittedly, this whole story is plagued by confusing notation! There is, at the same time, the function $x\in\overline K(E)\cong\overline K(x, y)$ which maps the point $(x, y)\in E$ to the number $x\in \overline K$. It's pretty horrific! Your (pretty understandable!) mistake is confusing the function $x\in\overline K(E)$ with the point $x\in \overline K$. So in the untwisted function field, $x^\sigma=x$ by definition. So on the functions $x,y\in \overline K(E)_\xi$, you get $x^\sigma=x$ and $y^\sigma =\chi(\sigma) y$.

Comment: If you then pick a point $(x', y')\in E_\chi(\overline K)$, you can think of it as the element $(x, \sqrt d y)\in E(\overline K)$ via the isomorphism $f$. You then have $\sigma(x', y') = (x'^\sigma, \chi(\sigma)y'^\sigma)$ as you've written.

Comment: @Mathmo123 that makes perfect sense....you are correct, I was confusing $x\in \bar{K}(E)$ with $x\in \bar{K}$, thank you very much.

Comment: @Mathmo123 your comments look like they might do well as an answer - would you consider writing them as such beow?

Comment: Could you tell me why $\sigma \cdot x= x$ ?